# Understand the internal hom simplicial set

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory

I am currently reading the paper "a short course on $\infty$-categories" by M.Groth. The Theorem 1.18 in this paper states:
A simplicial set $X$ is an $\infty$-category if and only if the restriction map $i^*:Map(\Delta^2,X)\to Map(\Lambda^2_1,X)$ is an acyclic Kan fibration.
The question I want to ask is regarding the understanding of the explanation part of this theorem. The author says, right after the theorem, that "We can think of $Map(\Lambda^2_1,X)$ as the space of composition problems and similarly of $Map(\Delta^2,X)$ as the space of solutionms to composition problems."
I wonder why would such statement hold? Because by definition $$Map(\Lambda^2_1,X)_n=Hom_{sSet}(\Delta^n\times\Lambda^2_1,X)$$
And this is not really the "composable" maps, i.e. $Hom_{sSet}(\Lambda^2_1,X)$. Similarly for $\Delta^2$ situation.
Thank you a lot for your help. I feel like this is a stupid question. Somehow I just cannot convince myself.

Comment: Set $n = 0$. The rest is higher dimensional data.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thanks I see that. But what info would the n>0 case tell us?

Comment: A space (simplicial set) consists of more than just points (vertices). The higher dimensional data tells you how the points are related to each other.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thanks a lot. Although I still have no idea how higher data works, it might show up later in the context I suppose!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplices of positive dimension in any simplicial set $X$ serve a role analogous to that of a topology on $X_0:$ they describe how the points of $X$ hang together. For instance, a $1$-simplex is simply a path between two points. If $X$ is a mapping simplicial set, as in your question, then the points are maps and the $1$-simplices are homotopies between maps!

In essence, in this context the higher simplices give you homotopies between homotopies. This would be literally true in a *cubical* set, but for technical and historical reasons simplicial sets are usually preferred. Both heuristically and rigorously, the overall information is the same. And the fact that simplicial sets (with the Kan model structure) and topological spaces are Quillen equivalent model categories is a formalization of the heuristic above that the higher simplices do the same kind of thing as a topology—specifically, this is literally true for questions that are homotopy-invariant. So for *homotopy theory*, you are absolutely safe in imagining that the higher simplices give a topology to the $0$-simplices, or that they define paths between paths between…in the set of $0$-simplices.

All this is to justify that something like $\mathrm{Map}(\Lambda^2_1,X)$ should roughly be thought of as the *space* of 2-D inner horns in $X.$ Then the condition given here says that we can define an $\infty$-category as a simplicial set which has the same *space* of inner horns as of 2-simplices—that is, you have a homotopy equivalence between those spaces, so that you can not only fill every inner horn, but you can do so *uniquely* up to a homotopy which is itself unique up to a higher homotopy, which is…

To be completely fair, there is one important refinement to this thinking. An $\infty$-category is not really like a space, but rather like some sort of “directed” space, since paths are not always reversible. However, it is the case that an equivalence of $\infty$-categories really does reduce to a pair of equivalences on the proper *spaces*, I.e. Kan complexes, of points and of edges. And Kan complexes themselves, which are the simplicial sets most definitively like spaces, are everywhere in the theory, for instance in the mapping sets at issue here.

Comment: The mapping simplicial sets here are not Kan complexes but merely quasicategories.

Comment: @ZhenLin I checked in Groth's notes and I believe he's using the mapping Kan complex, not the internal hom of simplicial sets.

Comment: Ah, no, I take it back. He discusses the Kan complexes Map_L, Map_R just above this, so I missed the correct interpretation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I am mostly confused by the intention of this characterization. Since I can think of $Map(\Lambda^2_1,X)$ as the space of inner horns in X and $Map(\Delta^2,X)$ as 2 simplices. Why would we need this than the original definition of an $\infty$-category? i.e. the map $Hom(\Delta^2,X)\to Hom(\Lambda^2_1,X)$ is surjective (although the definition should be $\Delta^n$ and $\Lambda^n_k$ for $0<k<n$, is simplifying the thing that we need to check from $n$ to $2$ the purpose?)